# Add slash suffix and not space for folder commands on bash auto-completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

What i expect my bash shell autocompletion to be like,

```
% cd $HOM<TAB>
-> cd $HOME/<CURSOR-HERE>
```

What it does to me,

```
% cd $HOM<TAB>
-> cd $HOME<SPACE><CURSOR-HERE>
```

How can i instruct bash to add a suffix slash and not space for folder commands?
I am using bash version -- `4.2.46 and centos - 7.1.1503`

Note: This is not due to [acroread issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acroread/+bug/769866/comments/7%20b) as the file acroread.sh is non-existent in my machine.

Comment: FYI plain bash 4.3 (`bash --norc --noprofile`) seems to behave as you expected.  It will get affected heavily by completion scripts, so you might want to write your own.

Comment: Post your `.bashrc`.

Comment: i tried `bash --norc --noprofile` with bash - 4.2. still, the problem is there. On other machine which has `bash 4.3`, i don't see this problem at all. Gilles, since `--norc -noprofile` didn't make it work, i don't think my .bashrc can help you in anyway?